# What is the best way to manage sessions in Node.js?

Tags: node.js, express, security, session, cookies

I'm learning Node.js, and I was wondering what is the best way to handle sessions.

It occurs to me that there are two main options: *express-session*, or *cookie-session*.

I did some research, and I've found that *express-session* is not the best way, since it stores all session information on the server, making it less scalable, but lots of tutorials were recommending it.

So, I am a little confused.

Comment: Depends what you need. If all you need is to store some per-client information between pages, you could just use localStorage/sessionStorage. No need for any library. But the client controls this data 100%, which isn't always good enough. Sometimes you'll need to be able to control the data from the server or when the user isn't logged in, and for that you need a server-based session.

Answer (score 1):

These two options are not comparable as they don't have the same functionality.

If you just want to set up a ["volatile" session](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cookie-session#semantics), with no need to store/verify any information server side, you can use cookie based session. This is just an improvement for the user experience (remember choices, preferences...)

On the other hand, if you need to keep some record about that user (authentication, history...), you will need to use a [server side session](https://github.com/expressjs/session), and a database. Any client side data (like cookie) could be modified by the user.

Note that the last option is not less scalable, it depends on the storage method, *MemoryStore* by default in express-session package, according to the documentation.
This package is powered by express team, so I guess it is robust enough for a production usage.